# How to append a numpy of mixed element types to another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I have a numpy array that I am using an if loop to filter out some unwanted entries, and I want to append the entries I want to keep to a new 'filtered array'.

```
from astropy.table import Table
import numpy as np

data = '/home/myname/data.fits'
data = Table.read(data, format="fits") 

ID = np.array(data['id'])
ID.astype(str)

redshift = np.array(data['z'])
redshift.astype(float)

radius = np.array(data['r']) 
radius.astype(float)

mag = np.array(data['magnitude'])
mag.astype(float)

def stack(array1, array2, array3, array4):
    #stacks multiple arrays to have corresponding values next to eachother
    stacked_array = [(array1[i], array2[i], array3[i], array4[i]) for i in range(0, array1.size)]
    stacked_array = np.array(stacked_array)
    return(stacked_array) 

stacked = stack(ID, redshift, radius, mag)

filtered_array = np.array([])

for i in stacked:
    if i.any == 'nan':
        np.delete(stacked[i])
    else:
       np.append(filtered_array, stacked[i])
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

Is there any way to append to the new array without getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a mess turn out I just needed to change the last line from:

```
np.append(filtered_array, stacked[i])
```

to

```
np.append(filtered_array, i)
```